# Access Excel Worksheet in C# class file using VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have created an Excel Addin using the VSTO Template (VS2010, Excel2007).
In the Solution Explorer, I have a group called Excel, and under that a file called ExcelAddIn.cs. This has access to the active worksheet through code like

```
public partial class MyAddIn
{
    Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Application.Activesheet;
    Excel.Range firstRow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1",missing);
}
```

etc. This code works fine ie. I can get at the Excel model.

Rather than put all my processing code in this one class file however, I'd like to work on Excel worksheet data in another class file. I have created this file, but am unable to use any code like the above in it, ie. I cannot seem to access the Excel model from this file.
I've duplicated the 'using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel' references, but putting in a line like:

```
Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Application.Activesheet;
```

gives me a 'The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context' error.

Any ideas on what references/changes I need to make to get at the Excel model from this separate class file?

btw. The file that works refers to an 'Excel.Application' object for that first code line, the second separate file that doesn't work is referring to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' object.

Thanks
Pete

==== FOUND ANSWER ====
The way to get at your worksheets from other classes you add is to simply access

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

for example:

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

where 'ThisAddIn' is the name of the class your wizard created (you may have renamed it).

So, use Globals to get at your Excel objects outside the ThisAddin code.

Comment: if someone could paste the answer code to the answer section, the question's closed! I can't - too much of a junior burger in here.Pete

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your own answer here:

The way to get at your worksheets from other classes you add is to simply access

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

for example:

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

where 'ThisAddIn' is the name of the class your wizard created (you may have renamed it).

So, use Globals to get at your Excel objects outside the ThisAddin code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because Application only ever exists when the Excel executable is running? Keep in mind Addins are specifically designed for this, and could have a 'special sauce' in the background that lets it interact the Office classes.

I dont think you would be able to call Application.Activesheet from another class as the Class you are calling from is completely unaware of the application's existence.

I realise I might be rambling a tad, I hope some of that made sense :)

In short, no I dont believe you can call Application.Activesheet like that, unless **maybe** you passed the 'Application' object through a constructor in your class instanciation.

ie.

```
MyClass c = new MyClass(this.Application);
```

...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Application app)
    {
        // And from here manipulate the Application object (just be sure you've added the reference to the namespace that the Application object uses)
    }

}
```

Im not sure if that would work though as I dont currently have my VM booted up :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Adam G. I think you're onto to it here. I'm wondering what people normally do in this situation, as I can't imagine they would restrict ALL their processing code to the add in class, but I may be wrong....will try a bit of passing and see how it goes. Thanks again Pete

Comment: Found the answer (but I can't answer my questions yet!)The way to get at your worksheets from other classes you add is to simply access

    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;

for example:

    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveSheet;

where 'ThisAddIn' is the name of the class your wizard created (you may have renamed it).

So, use Globals to get at your Excel objects outside the ThisAddin code.

Comment: and i think you need to choose 'add another answer' (or something similar), post your solution and then you can mark it as answer. i dont think you can mark as answer in the comments :)